# Sprite couldn't be removed from a sprite list in Unity2d using c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a project that displays a sprite from a folder with country images, where the user has to guess the country. Once I have selected a random sprite, I want to be able to remove that sprite from the list. However, I have been trying multiple methods which have not worked so far. I have tried .remove, .removeAt and .destroy and I still get the same error as shown below:

'Sprite' does not contain a definition for 'destroy' and no accessible extension method 'destroy' accepting a first argument of type 'Sprite' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

```
public class quizManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    [SerializeField] Sprite [] countryImages;
    [SerializeField] SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
    int randomNumber;

    public string correntCountry;
    

    void Start()
    {
        countryAppear();
    }

    public void countryAppear(){
        randomNumber = Random.Range(1, countryImages.Length);
        spriteRenderer.sprite = countryImages[randomNumber];
        
        countryImages.Remove(randomNumber); 
        
        currentCountry = countryImages[randomNumber].ToString().Split(' ')[0];
        
        

        Debug.Log(currentCountry.Split(' ')[0]);
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `List<Sprite>` instead of `Sprite[]`